# Creating Button programmatically

Tags: json, swift, button

I have a method witch is iterating through a JSON file

```
var items = [JSON]()
func getDataFromJSON(){
    //Calling getCollectionViewData from the RestParser class
    RestParser.sharedInstance.getConfig{json in
        //iterating to the JSON file to get alle data
        let results = json[0]["menu"]
        for (index: String,cofigData:JSON)in results{
          self.items.append(cofigData)
          self.createButton()
        }
        println(self.items.count)
        println(json)
    }

}
```

I and i want as much result there are in the "json array" to create buttons but some how it only creates one button and i dont know why ?

This is how i crate my button

```
func createButton(){

   let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 100,height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    //button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the expected result from `json[0]["menu"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does create a lot of buttons but since all of them have one frame `CGRect(x: 100,y: 100,width: 100,height: 50)` they lie upon each other. That's why you see just one. You need to assign each button its own frame

UPDATED:

```
func createButton(index : Int){

 let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100,y: 100 * index,width: 100,height: 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
//button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(button)
```

}

Then you just need to pass into `createButton` method current iteration index

Comment: how can i move them  ?

Comment: by assigning them a different frame. or center. Think of where you'd like the buttons to be placed and set appropriate coordinates

Comment: do you maybe have a quick and dirty solution for this ? so simply move them 50px down

Comment: so i can now just base reuslts.count that should be it